# How do I make my live jQuery search wait a second before performing the search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a search input which sends data from an input to a php file as I type. The php file does a search on my database and shows up a list of search options. You know, the ajax style live searching.

My problem is, if you type something really fast, it might just conduct a search off of the first 1 or 2 letters even though another 10 have been typed. This causes a few problems.

My jQuery looks a bit like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#searchMe').keyup(function(){
    lookup(this.value);
  });
});
```

and

```
function lookup(searchinput) {

  if(searchinput.length == 0) {
    // Hide the suggestion box.
    $("#suggestions").hide();
  } else {

    $('#loading').fadeIn();

    $.post("/RPCsearch.php", {queryString: ""+searchinput+""}, function(data){
      if(data.length > 0) {
        $("#suggestions").html(data).show();
        $('#loading').fadeOut();
      }
    });
  }
} // lookup
```

So I'm just curious, how can I make it so that my script waits until I've finished typing before running the function? My logic says something like if a key hasn't been pressed for 200 micro seconds, run the function, otherwise hold up a bit.

How is this done?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Easy, using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.setTimeout).  Of course you only want one timer going at once, so it's important to use [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.clearTimeout) at the beginning of the function...

```
$(function() {
  var timer;
  $("#searchMe").keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var ms = 200; // milliseconds
    var val = this.value;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      lookup(val);
    }, ms);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for this Josh. a few new things in there I haven't seen!

Answer (score 5):

You may be interested in my [`bindDelayed`](http://phrogz.net/jquery-bind-delayed-get) jQuery mini-plugin. It:

- Allows you to specify a delay before kicking off the request
- Automatically cancels any previous requests that were scheduled to go off
- Automatically cancels any in-air XHR requests that were in progress when you make your request
- Only invokes your callback for the latest request

  - *If the user types "s", waits long enough for the request to go out, and then types "a", and the response for "s" comes back before the response for "sa" you won't have to deal with it.*

The answer to the original question using `bindDelayed` would look like so:

```
// Wait 200ms before sending a request,
// avoiding, cancelling, or ignoring previous requests
$('#searchMe').bindDelayed('keyup',200,'/RPCsearch.php',function(){
  // Construct the data to send with the search each time
  return {queryString:this.value};
},function(html){
  // Use the response, secure in the knowledge that this is the right response
  $("#suggestions").html(html).show();
},'html','post');
```

In case my site is down, here's the plugin code for Stack Overflow posterity:

```
(function($){
  // Instructions: http://phrogz.net/jquery-bind-delayed-get
  // Copyright:    Gavin Kistner, !@phrogz.net
  // License:      http://phrogz.net/js/_ReuseLicense.txt
  $.fn.bindDelayed = function(event,delay,url,dataCallback,callback,dataType,action){
    var xhr, timer, ct=0;
    return this.on(event,function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      if (xhr) xhr.abort();
      timer = setTimeout(function(){
        var id = ++ct;
        xhr = $.ajax({
          type:action||'get',
          url:url,
          data:dataCallback && dataCallback(),
          dataType:dataType||'json',
          success:function(data){
            xhr = null;
            if (id==ct) callback.call(this,data);
          }
        });
      },delay);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That is a cool mini plugin! Thanks for writing and sharing that @Phrogz!

Answer (score 3):

You really ought to look at using the jQuery [autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) plugin.  I find this plugin to be very useful and it already does what you need.  Look particularly at the delay [option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions), which you can customize to change how long the plugin waits after a keystroke to run.

Comment: cheers, i would use a plugin i just thought its such a small thing to do and i had half the code in place already there wasn't much point to installing one. thanks anyways!

Comment: ++ just May please change your avatar? When I see your answers anywhere, I feel this website is related to medical `:-)` ..! *(that's because of your white clothing)*

Answer (score 1):

1 solution in psuedocode:

```
OnKeyPress()
    txt = getTxt
    sleep(200)
    newTxt = getTxt
    if (txt == newTxt)  // nothing has been typed so do something
       run my thing
```

Answer (score 1):

this one is happy

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#searchMe").keyup(function () {

  try{window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);}catch(e){}
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(run, 2000); //delay

  function run()
  {      //dowhatev
    var text = $("#searchMe").val();
    //$("#showit").html(text);       
  }     
 });   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found the best success when attaching the event to keypress, keydown, and keyup inputs.  Safari/FireFox/IE all seem to handle special keypresses (delete, backspace, etc.) a bit differently but using all events together seems to cover it.  The only way that running all events works though is to use setTimeout so that when they all fire it just resets the timer and ultimately the callback only gets executed once.

```
var delay = 200;
var search_timer = null;
$("#searchMe").keydown(function(e) {
    if(search_timer) {
        clearTimeout(search_timer);
    }
    search_timer = setTimeout(lookup, delay);
});
$("#searchMe").keypress(function(e) {
    if(search_timer) {
        clearTimeout(search_timer);
    }
    search_timer = setTimeout(lookup, delay);
});
$("#searchMe").keyup(function(e) {
    if(search_timer) {
        clearTimeout(search_timer);
    }
    search_timer = setTimeout(lookup, delay);
});
```