# Optimised search using Ajax and keypress

Tags: jquery, ajax, search, keypress

I have the following code that I want to use to search a database as a user is typing into a textbox. The code below works fine but it seems a little inefficient, as if a user is typing really fast. I am potentially doing many more searches than necessary. So if a user is typing in "sailing", I am searching on "sail", "saili", "sailin", and "sailing".

I wanted to see if there was a way to detect any particular time between keypresses so only search if user stops typing for 500 milliseconds or something like this.

Is there a best practice for something like this?

```
$('#searchString').keypress(function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        var url = '/Tracker/Search/' + $("#searchString").val();
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('div#results').html(data);
            $('#results').show();
        });
    }
    else {

        var existingString = $("#searchString").val();
        if (existingString.length > 2) {
            var url = '/Tracker/Search/' + existingString;
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                $('div#results').html(data);
                $('#results').show();
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#searchString').keyup(function(e) {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
      search(true);
    else
      $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 500));
});
function search(force) {
    var existingString = $("#searchString").val();
    if (!force && existingString.length < 3) return; //wasn't enter, not > 2 char
    $.get('/Tracker/Search/' + existingString, function(data) {
        $('div#results').html(data);
        $('#results').show();
    });
}
```

What this does is perform a search (on `keyup`, better than `keypress` for these situations) after `500ms` by storing a timer on the `#searchString` element's [`.data()` collection](http://api.jquery.com/data/).  Every `keyup` it clears that timer, and if the key was enter, searches immediately, if it wasn't sets a another `500ms` timeout before auto-searching.

Comment: If anyone's facing trouble with this code, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1171758/849829

Comment: The typing-and-search is working for me, but when i press enter it reloads the page. Why it would be happening?

Comment: @JoabR2D2 maybe you have a `<form>` tag/parent of your `<input type='text'>`

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez yeah it was there, but i have to keep the form and I'm using a prevenDefault() to solve it.

Comment: @JoabR2D2 then your `e.preventDefault()` is not working because it redirects to your form action try `return false` maybe. or better dont use a `<form>` tag if its not really necessary.

Comment: No, it solved the problem. it's working now. Thanks anyway. o/

Comment: Using `input` instead of `keyup` is even better. It not only covers paste or cut actions from the user, it's also faster.

Answer (score 3):

See this older question:

[How do I make my live jQuery search wait a second before performing the search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171582/how-do-i-make-my-live-jquery-search-wait-a-second-before-performing-the-search)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is each key press use a setTimeout function with the desired delay. So that function will fire after that timeout. Each key press then delete the timer and set a new one, with clearTimeout();

See here for some examples, scrolling past all the adverts.

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add some more points to the question.
Throttling and debounce concepts are related to this topics.

**Throttling :** 
It will make you to execute the function in a specified interval.

**Debounce :**
It will make you to execute the function when user has stopped typing.

You can achieve this two by setimeout , cleartimeout functions.Check this link will give you a clear walk-through of it.

[LINK](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/debouncing-and-throttling-in-javascript)

Comment: Describe your solution direct on SO.