# Slow down AJAX function with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got an ajax search function on my site that works great! However, I see that it could potentially lead to unused httpResquests due to speedy typers. So I would like to add a timer to slow the search down.

First thing that came to mind was a setTimeout but it's not working. It seems to work (pause the search) the first time around but after results are shown then it just kinda goes back to normal showing results the second my key is up. So after I noticed it wasn't working for whatever reason I turned to stackoverflow and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028704/optimized-search-using-ajax-and-keypress) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171582/how-do-i-make-my-live-jquery-search-wait-a-second-before-performing-the-search) but they basically do exactly what I did.

I'm thinking it might have something to do with the asynchronous ways of AJAX and maybe the method is called in the setTimeout before the time actually is up but that doesen't make much sense. So to be completely honest I have no idea what's going on any insight would be much appreciated. Oh and I use my own API I'm sure just glancing at the method names you'll know exactly what they do.

```
function validateNetworkInput()
{
    var query, timer = null;

    query = getValue("searchNetworkInput");

    if(query.length > 0)
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        show("searchNetworkWrapper");       
        timer = setTimeout(function(){searchNetworks(query);}, 3000);
    }
    else
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        hide("searchNetworkWrapper");
    }
}
```

...

```
function searchNetworks(query)
{
    var ajaxObject, params, path;

    ajaxObject = getAjaxObject();
    params = "?q=" + query;
    path = getInternalPath() + "searchNetworks" + params;

    ajaxObject.open("GET", path, true);
    ajaxObject.send();

    ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(ajaxObject.readyState == 4 && ajaxObject.status == 200)
        {
            setInnerHtml("searchNetworkWrapper", ajaxObject.responseText);
        }
        else if (ajaxObject.readyState == 4 && ajaxObject.status != 200)
        {
            getErrorReport("Error Searching Networks", "search our database for the network you are looking for");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You've tagged this `jQuery`, so why not use `jQuery.ajax`? It'll simplify your life drastically.

Comment: Tag removed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `timer` is local to your function, so it won't remember the old timer the next time it is called. You need a variable that will stick around between function invocations. Something like this should work:

```
var validateNetworkInput = (function() {
  var timer;
  return function() {
    var query = getValue("searchNetworkInput");

    clearTimeout(timer);
    if(query.length > 0) {
        show("searchNetworkWrapper");       
        timer = setTimeout(function(){searchNetworks(query);}, 3000);
    } else {
        hide("searchNetworkWrapper");
    }
})();
```

Comment: Of course! That's embarassing, can't believe I forgot! Will accept in three thanks a ton