# Delayed javascript/jQuery search using TypeScript not waiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, settimeout

I'm trying to build a simple delayed search with `TypeScript`. I used the answer as described here [@stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1171758/615288).

Currently, my script looks like this:

```
$searchInput: JQuery;

timer: number;
waitTimeOut = 3000;

init() : void{
    this.$searchInput.on("input propertychange paste", this.handleSearchInputChange);
}

handleSearchInputChange = (evt: Event): void => {
    var $theInput = $(evt.currentTarget);

    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    var val = $theInput.val();
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.lookup(val), this.waitTimeOut);
}

lookup = (searchTerm: string): void => {
    console.log(`I should start a search with [${searchTerm}]`);
}
```

However, there is no delay at all. Each typed letter triggers immediately the `lookup`-call.
Is this some scope-issue with `timer` and `waitTimeOut`? Or are the 'function-definitions' in the wrong scope?

Still not sure if using the `fat-arrow` is correct here or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your current implementation, you are currently invoking the function `lookup(val)` and passing its return value  to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) accepts code in string format or function to execute which delayed interval.

*Use*

```
var self = this;
this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
    self.lookup(val);
}, this.waitTimeOut);
```

*instead of*

```
this.timer = setTimeout(this.lookup(val), this.waitTimeOut);
```

Comment: I changed as in your answer and `ReSharper` suggested me, to use `Convert to lambda-expression`. This removes the `self` and changes the first parameter to `() => { this.lookup(val) }`. Now I'm a bit confused what typescript is exactly doing here under the hood.

Comment: @KingKerosin, I am not good with TypeScript hence can't help you there, mine was Plain vanilla JS script